# Persistently tracking user input asynchronously using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm seeking a Python script that persistently awaits user input for some time at each interval. Should the user fail to provide input within this timeframe, the script should automatically execute a predefined operation and continue this process indefinitely. In other words, I require a routine that perpetually runs, yet swiftly evaluates any character input by the user.

To achieve this, I've crafted a code snippet wherein the `getch` function captures a character input from the user. The program awaits the user's input within a timeout period. If the user fails to provide input within this interval, a notification is issued to indicate that the time has elapsed.

```py
import threading


def getch(input_str: list) -> None:
    """Gets a single character"""
    try:
        import msvcrt

        input_str.append(msvcrt.getch().decode("utf-8"))
    except ImportError:
        import sys
        import termios
        import tty

        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        oldsettings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(fd)
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, oldsettings)
        input_str.append(ch)


def input_with_timeout(timeout):
    print("You have {} seconds to enter something:".format(timeout))
    input_str = []
    input_thread = threading.Thread(target=getch, args=(input_str,))
    input_thread.start()
    input_thread.join(timeout)

    if input_thread.is_alive():
        print("Time's up! Performing default operation.")
    else:
        print("You entered:", input_str)


while True:
    input_with_timeout(5)
```

When the user provides input within the allotted time, the system functions correctly. However, should time elapse, two issues arise: firstly, there is a glitch in text display, resulting in misplacement of the text, and secondly, the user must input their response multiple times, as a single attempt does not seem to register the input accurately.

[image]
Because libraries such as [pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/limitations.html) and [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) have limitations in some environments, I cannot use them.

Comment: From https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html on `.getch()` "This call will block if a keypress is not already available". 'Asynchronous' and 'continuous' are somewhat contradictory. Calling a `list` parameter `input_str` is more than a little confusing. What exactly is your question though?

Comment: I want an action to always be executed, but if the user enters a character, it will quickly check the user's character. For example, this code waits for the user's input for 5 seconds, and if he doesn't input it, it performs another action, almost like an event loop.

Comment: You say `keyboard` has some limitations in some environments, but then you're using `msvcrt`, which is entirely specific to Windows, specifically the MS VC++ runtime. What limitations are stopping you from using `keyboard`, which would make the problem almost trivial?

Comment: I tested the `getch` function on both Linux and Windows and it worked. If the operating system is not Windows, the second part of the function is executed. In Linux, to run the `keyboard` code, it needs to be run with root access

Comment: What about `pynput`? Why can't that be run in this environment?

Comment: The problem I encountered was that it didn't work properly in the ‍`Wayland` Ubuntu environment and a series of things needed to be installed, but this code that I found from stackoverflow works in several environments that I tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're happy to use `msvcrt`, what is wrong with this type of minimal implementation?

```
import threading
import time
import msvcrt


def periodical():
    while True:
        print("\nPrint periodic message")
        time.sleep(3)


def listen_for_keypress():
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():  
            key = msvcrt.getch()
            print(f"\nKey pressed: {key.decode('utf-8')}", end='')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target=periodical, daemon=True).start()
    listen_for_keypress()
```

Note that this won't work correctly when run directly from an environment like PyCharm, since its console implementation doesn't function like the standard console like Windows Console Host or Windows Terminal. But in either of those, it seems to do what you require?

My example prints a message periodically, but of course it could also just terminate if you have a way to communicate that fact:

```
import threading
import time
import msvcrt


def application_timeout(timeout, stop_event):
    time.sleep(timeout)
    stop_event.set()  # signal stop


def listen_for_keypress(stop_event):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            key = msvcrt.getch()
            print(f"\nKey pressed: {key.decode('utf-8')}", end='')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    stop = threading.Event()
    threading.Thread(target=application_timeout, args=(3, stop), daemon=True).start()

    listen_for_keypress(stop)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this code works well in the Windows environment, I will try to use your idea and the above code to make it work in the Linux environment as well.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing upon [Grismar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78196830/8157102) and integrating it with the ‍`getch` function mentioned earlier, I conducted tests on Windows 11, Ubuntu 22.04, and Debian 12 GNOME platforms, and the code performed satisfactorily.

```py
import threading
import time


def getch(input_str: list) -> None:
    while True:
        """Gets a single character"""
        try:
            import msvcrt

            input_str.append(msvcrt.getch().decode("utf-8"))
        except ImportError:
            import sys
            import termios
            import tty

            fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
            oldsettings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
            try:
                tty.setraw(fd)
                ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
            finally:
                termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, oldsettings)
            input_str.append(ch)


def periodical(input_str: list):
    while True:
        print("\033c")
        print(f"\nPrint periodic message, user_inputs: {input_str}")
        time.sleep(3)


while True:
    input_str = []
    t = threading.Thread(target=periodical, args=(input_str,), daemon=True).start()
    getch(input_str)
```